# probability: metal detector at airport

Tags: probability

There is a metal detector in an airport, and 49 people in a line in front of it. Four of these people (chosen at random beforehand), have metal in their pockets. The people go through the metal detector until someone with the metal does, then the alarm sounds. What’s the average amount of people that go through the metal detector before the alarm sounds for the first time?

Hint: the four people with the metal split the other 45 into 5 different groups

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: The hint looks useful

Comment: @Henry do we need all five parts? It seems to me that we just need to care about where the first of the 4 people is located?

Comment: @Boshu The point of the hint is to say that people without metal can go before the first metal person (which is what you care about) or in one of the three gaps between the metal people or after the last metal person, so five gaps in total.  The number of non-metal people in each of these five gaps is binomially distributed (with identical but not independent distributions).  So the answer is easy

Comment: Alternatively, what is the probability that a particular non-metal person comes before all four metal people?  Then use linearity of expectation, again for an easy answer.

Comment: @Henry oh I think that is an alternate solution to mine. I'm not sure that is the most helpful given the statistic we need to calculate, but I see why that was a hint. I think my approach below should also be correct?

Comment: @Boshu Since true blue anil has in effect repeated both my comments in an answer, all you need to do is check whether your answer also gives $\frac{45}{5}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going according to the hint, the $4$ people with metal  can be considered as separators that, on an average, divide the queue into five equal parts of $9$ "safe" people, thus the first metal  is expected to  be seen **after** $9$ people, **at** position $10$.

This follows from linearity of expectation, which operates even when the variables are not independent.

---

**Added**

More formally, there are $4$ "specified" people with metal, and $45$ "others".
Let $X_i$ be an indicator random variable that assumes a value of $1$ if the $i^{th}$ "other" person is ahead of the first specified one, and $0$ otherwise.

Consider the $i^{th}\;$ "other" person together with the $4$ specified ones.
Since each "other" person is equally likely to be ahead of the first specified one,
P($i^{th}\;$ "other" person is before the first one)  $=\frac1{4+1}$

Now the expectation of an indicator random variable is just the probability of the event it indicates, so $\Bbb E[X_i]=\frac15$

And by linearity of expectation, we have  $\Bbb E[X] = 45\cdot\large\frac15 = 9\;$ **before** the first specified